# How to use Chrome dev tools to debug javascript tag added dynamically to a page's head element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to use Chrome's dev tools to debug the flow of javascript on a page. I have a 3rd party system that loads javascript that dynamically adds a SCRIPT tag to the HEAD element on the page using some code like:

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.src = 'https://address.com/anotherjsscript.js';
head.appendChild(el);
```

How can I catch the "anotherjsscript.js" as it is dynamically loaded and debug into that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although BenG's answer will cover most cases, my case was badly obfuscated with a different filename dynamically served each time.  My solution was to add an event listener for "Script first statement" and then laboriously work through all the other scripts until I hit the one I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

I just used your code above pointing to jQuery Validation:-

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js';
head.appendChild(el);
```

After letting the page run for the 1st time, you will see the request under the *Network* Tab, right click on the script and select *Open in source panel* :-

[image]

then add your break point and refresh the page again:-

[image]

Which should then get hit.

#### Option 2

Another option is to create a function like below, which gets the script content, prepend a `debugger` and set the scripts text to the content:-

```
function debugScript(url){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var script = 'debugger; ' + xmlHttp.responseText;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var el = document.createElement('script');
    el.type = 'text/javascript';
    el.text = script;
    head.appendChild(el);
}

debugScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js');
```

The breakpoint will get hit as long as the developer tools is open.

Comment: Thanks BenG.  My example is annoying more obfuscated in that it in fact seems to be giving me a dynamically generated *different* filename every time.  Still your answer seems to be good for 95% of cases!

Comment: please see the other option added in my answer. should make things much easier for you :)

Comment: BenG, nice again, but I'm working with a really locked down 3rd party tool.  The code to do the adding of the script to the file is also in a file I don't have access to make changes to :(